# PHP MySQL repopulate multiselect list

Tags: php, mysql, multi-select

I have got a multiselect defined in the following way:

```
<select id="slctAdditional" name="slctAdditional[]" size="1"     class="drop_down" style="WIDTH: 300px; MARGIN: 5px 0 0 0; POSITION: relative;" VALUE="">
      <option value="50ffbee0768642.23917400_127.0.0.1">blah blah</option>
      <option value="50ffbee0768642.23917410_127.0.0.1">blah blah</option>
      <option value="50ffbee0768642.23917420_127.0.0.1">blah blah</option>
      <option value="50ffbee0768642.23917430_127.0.0.1">blah blah</option>
      <option value="50ffbee0768642.23917440_127.0.0.1">blah blah</option>

   </select>
```

I manage to store the selected items into a MySQL database using PHP.

```
50ffbee0768642.23917410_127.0.0.1
50ffbee0768642.23917420_127.0.0.1
```

Now I don't know how to reselect these two items when I want to display the list back for editing. Can you help?

Comment: To whoever marked this question down. I found similar answers to my question but using jquery approach that was not useful for me.Time was also an issue for me. It might be a trivial question to you but for me was not. By marking my question down you just demonstrate to be arrogant and selfish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get all Items stored in Database in a array.
2. In HTML check whether the value present in that array.

   ```
    <?php
        $selected_vals  = 1D array from DB
    ?>

   <select id="slctAdditional" name="slctAdditional[]" size="1"     class="drop_down" style="WIDTH: 300px; MARGIN: 5px 0 0 0; POSITION: relative;" VALUE="">
     <option <?php if(in_array('50ffbee0768642.23917400_127.0.0.1',$selected_vals)){?> selected="selected" <?php }?> value="50ffbee0768642.23917400_127.0.0.1">blah blah</option>
     <option value="50ffbee0768642.23917410_127.0.0.1">blah blah</option>
     <option value="50ffbee0768642.23917420_127.0.0.1">blah blah</option>
     <option value="50ffbee0768642.23917430_127.0.0.1">blah blah</option>
     <option value="50ffbee0768642.23917440_127.0.0.1">blah blah</option>
   ```

Add this for all the options `<?php if(in_array('50ffbee0768642.23917400_127.0.0.1',$selected_vals)){?> selected="selected" <?php }?>`

Answer (score 0):

To set an option in a select box as the default selected, you add the "selected" property to it.

```
<option value="XXXX" selected>Something</option>
```

So, when you create the list of options, see if that value is equal to the value in the database.

```
<option value="50ffbee0768642.23917410_127.0.0.1" <?=($DB_VALUE=='50ffbee0768642.23917410_127.0.0.1' ?'selected' : '')?>>blah blah</option>
<option value="50ffbee0768642.23917420_127.0.0.1" <?=($DB_VALUE=='50ffbee0768642.23917420_127.0.0.1' ?'selected' : '')?>>blah blah</option>
```